What should I do about these holes? They had screws in them before I moved into this house
This is in a half bathroom the screw holes held a mirror (I'll add a photo of it here if I can). Unfortunately I'm a noob with this kind of stuff and the cuts were unfortunately from me trying to put the screws back and have the mirror hanging at an even level. I'm sure I could potentially insert some caulk or something in the holes and other stuff in the back of the mirror to keep it all in place but for now this is what I have. All suggestions are appreciated.






Fill them with spackle and touch up the paint.

Get some vinyl spackling and fill in the holes. Try to cut away the loose paper and cardboard. Once the holes are filled, stick a little extra spackling over the holes and try to match the texture of of wall. Touch up with paint if a noticeable difference. I wouldn't use caulk unless it's the paintable type.
